# cuda occupancy calculator

Tags: cuda

i used --ptax-options=-v while compiling my .cu code, it gave the following:

```
ptxas info: Used 74 registers, 124 bytes smem, 16 bytes cmem[1]
```

devQuery for my card returns the following:

```
rev:  2.0
name: tesla c2050
total shared memory per block: 49152
total reg. per block: 32768
```

now, i input these data into cuda occupancy calculator as follows:

```
1.) 2.0
1.b) 49152
2.) threads per block: x
    registers per thread: 74
    shared memory per block (bytes): 124
```

i was varying the x (threads per block) so that x*74<=32768. for example, i enter 128 (or 256) in place of x. Am I entering all the required values by occupancy calculator correctly? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ptxas-options=--verbose` (or -v) produces output of the format

```
ptxas : info : Compiling entry function '_Z13matrixMulCUDAILi16EEvPfS0_S0_ii' for 'sm_10'
ptxas : info : Used 15 registers, 2084 bytes smem, 12 bytes cmem[1]
```

The critical information is

- 1st line has the target architecture
- 2nd line has `<Registers Per Thread>, <Static Shared Memory Per Block>, <Constant Memory Per Kernel>`

When you fill in the occupancy calculator

- Set field 1.) Select Compute Capability to 'sm_10' in the above example
- Set field 2.) Register Per Thread to
- Set field 2.) Share Memory Per Block to  + DynamicSharedMemoryPerBlock passed as 3rd parameter to `<<<GridDim, BlockDim, DynamicSharedMemoryPerBlock, Stream>>>`

The Occupancy Calculator Help tab contains additional information.

In your example I believe you are not correctly setting field 1 as Fermi architecture is limited to 63 Registers Per Thread. sm_1* supports a limit of 124 Registers Per Thread.

Comment: In my case I have 'sm_13' (-arch=sm_13), and i call kernel only as <<<GridDim,BlockDim>>>. So i have to do: Set field 1 = 1.3; Set field 2 = 74; Set field 3 = 124. Is this right? Thanks!