# in CUDA, How does a thread block gets mapped to the SM's

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

Suppose a thread block contains 1000 threads and a Streaming multiprocessor(SM) can only execute 500 threads, then my thread block should be mapped to 2 or more SM's. then how can they access the shared memory?

Answer (score 3):

> .....then my thread block should be mapped to 2 or more SM's.

That isn't correct. Blocks are only ever mapped to a single multiprocessor for their complete lifecycle. It is never possible for a block to be split over multiple SM.

If you try and launch a kernel where the block size or resource requirements exceeds that of the multiprocessor on which it must run, the launch will fail and the kernel will never run at all.

Comment: But as a programmer how do we know, how many threads we can put in a block so that it wont exceed the SM's threads? As, no of threads executed on SM's depend on GPU archtecture.

Comment: By reading [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities) where the hardware limits of each generation of hardware are thoroughly described. And by using the [occupancy calculator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080248/cuda-occupancy-calculator) which is supplied in every version of the CUDA toolkit.

Comment: Also, take a look at the `deviceQuery` [sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#utilities).